# Zend Framework - how to disable one or more modules 

Tags: php, zend-framework

currelntly Im working on some project (based on ZF) and Im wondering if it's possible to turn off one or more modules. By turn off I mean ZF wont load it at all.

To be more precise I would like to turn off one of the exiting app module.
Let say my App contains some modules written by sombody else and I for the time beeing
I dont wanna use it.
I hope this question make sense for you.

--
Best Regards,
Robert

Comment: do you mean one of Zend Framework components? like Zend_Form? or one of the modules of your application?

Comment: what do you understand by core_module? can you give an example?

Answer (score 3):

If I understood right and you want to disable a module (group of views/controllers) from your site, you can register a `routeShutdown()` `FrontController` plugin that checks the routed request. If it is disabled, then you redirect the user to an error controller.

Create a plugin that checks if the requested module is disabled

```
class MyDisabledModules extends Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract
{
    protected $_disabled = array(
        'module1',
        'module2',
        'sales',
    );


    public function routeShutdown(Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request)
    {
        $module = $request->getModuleName();

        if (in_array($module, $this->_disabled)) {
            $request->setModuleName('default')
                    ->setControllerName('disabled')
                    ->setActionName('index')
                    ->dispatched(false);
        }
    }
}
```

and then register it in the `FrontController`:

```
Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()
    ->registerPlugin(new MyDisabledModules());
```

You can hardcode the disabled plugins, you can fetch them from a database, a xml, from everything you want.

Comment: more or less it's somethin I would like to achieve. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

I think that what Luiz Damim proposed is overkill and wrong. The plugin will be called for each call unnecessary. Why doing stuff for disabled modules?

I would do a detection based on a config file where only active modules are instantiated.

**UPDATE**
Usually modules are instantiated en masse:

```
$front->addModuleDirectory('/path/to/application/modules');
```

But you can activate modules one by one, or by passing an array with ONLY the ones that you want active.

```
$front->setControllerDirectory(array(
    'default' => '/path/to/application/controllers',
    'blog'    => '/path/to/application/blog/controllers'
));
```

If you are using Zend_application, I think you have to change this line in your config:

```
resources.modules[] =
```

with

```
resources.modules = admin
resources.modules = news
```

The first one loads whatever modules can find in the modules folder which is by default behaviour. I haven't worked yet with Zend Application so I am not sure about this, but there must be something like this.

Comment: In this case how you would do it ? Of coz I could add a list of active modules but finally I would have to check if called module is on the white list(has proper entry in config file).    
Best Regards,    
Robert